# Reload Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on adding a functionality to remove an account from my Chrome extension. I am using `Vue` and I have this:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    sync: sessionStorage,
    state:{
        accounts:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accounts')) || {}
    },  
    mutations:{
        addAccount(state,account){
            state.accounts[account.apikey] = account
            localStorage.setItem(
                "accounts",
                JSON.stringify(state.accounts)
            );  
        },  
        removeAccount(state,account){
            const accounts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accounts'));
            delete accounts[account.apikey];
            localStorage.setItem(
                "accounts",
                JSON.stringify(accounts)
            );  
            chrome.runtime.reload();
        }   
    },  
    getters:{
        accounts(state){
            return state.accounts;
        }   
    }   
})
```

Initially I did not plan on reloading the extension, but for some reason I couldn't figure out how to show the changes on the extension page. The account was removed from `local.storage`, but the extension still showed it.
Anyway, I am using `chrome.runtime.reload();` to reload the extension, but it doesn't actually reload it. It just closes it but never opens it back up.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Reloading means the entire package is reloaded just like it does on an extension update, and any open tabs/popups/windows with the extension's own pages will be just closed. Chrome won't reopen them automatically. You should really find the reason your state is not reset, instead of carpet-bombing it.

Comment: @wOxxOm okay thanks for the explanation.